# Why aren't ".targets" files imported from Directory.Buid.props not visible in Solution Explorer "Imports" folder?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2022

## Solved

The targets WAS there, just buried under Sdk.props->Microsoft.Common.props, which makes sense as that's where it would have been loaded from. My bad.

## The Problem

There is a nice feature that displays imported "*.props" and "*.targets" files in Solution Explorer.  These do not seem to display files imported from Directory.Build.props files.

This might be a feature or a bug in Visual Studio or maybe I'm doing something wrong.  It is not critical since it is correctly using the Targets2.target file, but it would be helpful to see all my targets files used.

Does anyone understand why this is happening and if there is a change I can make?

This has also been asked in Microsoft Feedback https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/targets-from-directorybuildprops-missing-in-soluti/1605185

## Setup C# Project

- (or clone https://github.com/MafuJosh/ReproduceVS2022BugDec2021)
- in Visual Studio 2022 Pro: Create New Project Class Library - C# - .NET 6
- edit the .csproj file, add:

```xml
<ImportGroup>
    <Import Project="Targets1.targets" />
</ImportGroup>
```

- create Targets1.targets text file in the project folder:

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="Test1" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="from Targets1" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

- create Targets2.targets text file in the project folder:

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="Test2" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="from Targets2" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

- create Directory.Build.props text file in the project folder:

```xml
<Project>
  <Import Project="Targets2.targets" />
</Project>
```

[image]

## Build C# Project

- build the project
- in Solution Explorer, Show All Files
- under now visible Imports folder, we see Targets1.target but not Targets2.target
- they both work but only one shows up under the Imports folder

[image: Visual Studio Solution Explorer]

Comment: directory-build-props is a new tag to stack overflow... I figured if app-config is one, so should this be

Comment: MSBuild is a very flexible system so people can use it in any way they like, but VS offers only a limited set of features (so it might not go and analyze `Directory.Build.props`). Since it has been reported to Microsoft already, your only hope is that Microsoft someday fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The targets WAS there, just buried under Sdk.props->Microsoft.Common.props, which makes sense as that's where it would have been loaded from.  My bad.